# Referencing a UserControl from a another UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got some embedded user controls in this project I'm stuck with and while trying to access a button state in the parent control my return value isn't what I'm expecting.

```
 var parentControl = (OrderDetail)this.Parent.Parent;

        // set return based on the OrderDetail control button state
        UltraButton btn = parentControl.Controls.Find("btnReturn", true).FirstOrDefault() as UltraButton;
```

That always returns btn.Enabled = true back to me, even though when the form is done loading the button I am referencing here is not enabled. Is there a lifecycle thing I am just not aware of here?

Delving into winforms is rare for me, so I'm sure I'm missing something, just not sure what it is yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough code to help you.  `this.Parent.Parent` is asking for trouble.  UserControls shouldn't really be talking to other UserControls.  It would probably be better to just set a property reference in the UserControls and have the mother form wire the properties together if they really need to talk to each other.

Comment: I'm not sure that `btn.Enabled` should be `false` unless your unset it manualy.

Comment: It turns out that the load even of the detail user control is firing before the button is set , just one of things you learn about winforms. I was able to get what I wanted by checking state in the OnVisibleChange event of the child user control. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Placed my code into the OnVisibleChanged event.

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);

        if (Visible && !Disposing)
        {
            // set return change option based on the OrderDetail control button state
            UltraButton btn = parentControl.Controls.Find("btnReturn", true).FirstOrDefault() as UltraButton;

            if (btn != null && (HasPermissions && btn.Enabled))
                actionAllowed = true;
        }
    }
```